# JQuery click events do not hide svg

Tags: jquery, svg

I am trying to get a working nav-bar that hides/shows and `svg` element. JQuery, however does not respond correctly. My code is as follows:

*HTML*

```
<header id="header"><h1 class="title">Test</h1></header>
<nav id="nav">
    <p class="text" data-index="0">Test</p>
    <p class="text" data-index="1">Test</p>
    <p class="text" data-index="2">Test</p>
    <p class="text" data-index="3">Test</p>
    <p class="text" data-index="4">Test</p>
</nav>
<div id="main" class="center">
    <svg width="1000" height="200" id="timeline">
        <line x1="0" y1="200"
              x2="1000" y2="200"
              stroke="black"
              stroke-width="4"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

*JavaScript*

```
$(".text").click(function(event) {
    var index = $(event.target).data("index");
    switch(index) {
        case "0":
            $("#timeline").hide("slow");
            break;
        case "1":
            $("#timeline").show("slow");
            break;
    }
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle demonstrating a full example: https://jsfiddle.net/James_Parsons/s0gze1qq/1/

Comment: You forgot to add jQuery library in your fiddle ;)

Comment: Whoops sorry about that :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indices are numbers, not strings, therefore you should use:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/h7m7p5co/) - <sub>(as a side note, you weren't including jQuery)</sub>

```
$(".text").click(function(event) {
    var index = $(event.target).data("index");
    switch(index) {
        case 0:
            $("#timeline").hide("slow");
            break;
        case 1:
            $("#timeline").show("slow");
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: I though that as the attribute was a string in the html, the JS would also return a string.

Comment: Not necessarily. As JS is not static typed like Java, value can be interpreted as number,string or boolean. But I've no clue as to why it stopped at a number when it can also be a string. I hope someone answers that :)

Answer (score 1):

Issue is in the way you're doing the switch case.

```
var index = $(event.target).data("index");
```

This returns a number not a string value, so change your switch case like below and it will work.

```
    switch(index) {
        case 0:
            $("#timeline").hide("slow");
            break;
        case 1:
            $("#timeline").show("slow");
            break;
    }
```

Here's a Fiddle [fork](https://jsfiddle.net/fs7fx5zc/2/) with updated changes :)

Answer (score 1):

1. You did not include jquery.min.js in fiddle
2. change

from

```
var index = $(event.target).data("index");
```

to

```
var index = $(this).data("index");
```

**JS** code will like this,

```
$(".text").click(function(event) {
    var index = $(this).data("index");
    switch(index) {
        case "0":
            $("#timeline").hide("slow");
            break;
        case "1":
            $("#timeline").show("slow");
            break;
    }
});
```